# Copy all contents in Notepad and paste into Textarea in webpage

Tags: java, selenium

Is it possible to copy all contents(Ctrl+A) in the notepad file and paste into Textarea in the webpage using Java /Selenium ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is as follows:

Code to copy contents of file into a textbox on webpage: This code copies and pastes the contents of one text file into Google search textbox on google.com and hits search button.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class CopyFileToTextbox {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    File inFile = new File("D:\\path\\to\\notepad\\file\\TextFile1.txt");
    StringBuilder targetString = new StringBuilder("");
    try {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(inFile);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String s = null;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            targetString.append(s);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.name("q")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys(targetString);
    driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
    driver.quit();


}

}
```